# Usage of ~まんねん (関西弁)

Tags: usage, verbs, kansai-ben

Steven Seagal stars in two TV advertisements for the energy drink [アリナミン](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AA%E3%83%8A%E3%83%9F%E3%83%B3), as seen [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2_UH_XoZ_I) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCzkujr1hkU). In the first commercial he is shown using martial arts two dispatch his opponents, while in the second he is depicted clinging to the top of a car involved in a police chase. In both ads he looks worn out and the voice-over says 「こう見えても、疲れまんねん」.

Wikipedia gives the example of 行きます becoming 行きまんねん on the [大阪弁 page](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A7%E9%98%AA%E5%BC%81#.E8.A1.A8.E7.8F.BE), so 疲れまんねん presumably corresponds to 疲れます in 標準語.

How commonly is ~まんねん used? [This](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1320470853) answer from Yahoo! 知恵袋 suggests it's rare - if this is so, are the Seagal ads trying to portray a certain image by using this pattern?

Comment: Searching on Google for スティーブン・セガール 関西弁 brings up [claims](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q113085021) that he speaks 関西弁 as a result of living for years in 大阪の十三.

Comment: Yeah, I think 大阪のおっちゃん(older men in Okasa) often use ~まんねん, ~まんな～, ~まんで～, ~まっか? (which don't sound very elegant to me...hehe)

Comment: Keep in mind that まんねん is keigo level and it is fairly rare to see people using local language when speaking keigo. That is why you would see mostly only old people using it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sometimes hear ~~まんねん used to mean ~~んです in Osaka/Kansai. I think they use...

> - ちゃいますねん/ちゃいまんねん to mean 違うんです (the polite forms)
>     (We use ちゃうんです to mean 違うんです in Kyoto.)
> - ちゃうねん to mean 違うんだ (the casual forms)
> - ちゃいます to mean 違います (the polite forms)

So I'd say...

> - 疲れまんねん means 疲れるんです (the polite forms)
> - 疲れんねん means 疲れるんだ (the casual forms)

---

> How commonly is ~まんねん used?

I think we often hear older men in Osaka use ~~まんねん. We don't expect young people like high school/college students or stylish businessmen in smart suits & ties to say 疲れまんねん (unless they're joking) even if they're from Osaka.

> ...are the Seagal ads trying to portray a certain image by using this pattern?

Likewise, we expect an action star like Steven Seagal to always look cool and perfect. We don't expect him to look exhausted and whine 疲れまんねん, right after he dispatches his opponents or in the middle of a car chase. (The こう in こう見えても refers to something like "He's doing all these things with no difficulty.") And, he abruptly confesses; "こう見えても、疲れまんねん" in a tone that an older male Osakan in shabby clothes would use. This is quite unexpected, so that's why the commercials are pretty funny to us, draw attention and remain in our memories (and actually that's what they'd want their TV commercials to be, no? ^^) P.S. Sorry for my poor English.. please feel free to edit, TIA ^^

Answer (score 4):

I'm a Japanese from Niigata Prefecture, but I've came across a lot of people from Kansai.

「疲れまんねん」is just a way of saying「疲れますねん」.

「ねん」is almost added to any Kansaiben phrase. Such as:

- 「違います」is「ちゃうねん」in Kansaiben.
- 「なんですか？」is「なんやねん？」in Kansaiben.

Sometimes it is **'embedded'** inside phrases.

- 「そうとは違います」is「そうとちゃうねんな」in Kansaiben.

「ねん」is basically「だよ」「なの」「なのだ。」Swap it into the three possibilities and try to guess which matches the best.

Comment: I don't agree with your translations. You are passing `標準敬語` into `タメ語関西弁`. ie. `違います` should be `ちゃいます` rather than `ちゃうねん`.

Comment: Yeah [何]{なん}ですか? would be なんでっか?(cos they're polite forms), [何]{なん}なんだ? would be なんやねん? (cos they're casual forms) and そうとちゃうねんな would mean そうとはちがうんだ/そうじゃないんだな (they're causal forms)..but せやないねんな/そやないねんな sound more natural to me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a kansaiben expert, but I have heard this before. A professional Go (the board game) player from Kansai once played a bad move and then immediately exclaimed アホちゃいまんねん！パーでんねん！ (How stupid! I screwed everything up!)

The exclamation stuck with me because it was hilarious.

Anyway, ねん in kansaiben is supposedly derived from のだ, and ～まん I think is a shortening of ～ます.　(I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong)

Of course, in 標準語 you can't put ～ます before のだ (you have to use the regular verb form), but if it's Kansaiben, I guess it's okay.

So, 疲れまんねん = 疲れるんだ

Comment: 「アホちゃいまんねん、パーでんねん」means "How stupid! I screwed everything up!"?? (Btw I think that's a famous phrase said by 明石家さんま in a classic comedy show)

Comment: No! It means 'I'm not a slow, but I'm worthless!' You have to understand that 明石家さんま worked very long (10 yrs) to get famous as a comedian and he'd gotten over a hard time before he got popular.

Comment: @GreekFellows "You" have to understand.. >> Oh are you talking to me?

Comment: Oops sorry. Quite an impolite act. :)

Comment: @Greek Fellows: Just in case you misunderstood Chocolate’s comment, she did not claim that アホちゃいまんねん、パーでんねん meant “How stupid!  I screwed everything up!”  It is the answerer (Lloyd Vincent) who claimed it, and she questioned the validity of the claim.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito Ah. I think I misunderstood Chocolate's comment. I apologize.