# What's the un-contracted form of 何を言うてんねん?

Tags: contractions

I'm assuming that the first ん, after て, stands for る. However, I simply cannot parse the ねん that comes afterward. How exactly does "what the hell are you saying" become 何を言うてんねん, or if my first assumption is correct, 何を言うてるねん?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sentence in Osaka dialect and means "What are you saying?" The "un-contracted" form would be 何を言っているねん (I know this sounds weird; see below).

- 言うて is an equivalent of 言って, the te-form of 言う. It's widely used in western part of Japan, including Osaka. It's pronounced as ゆーて.
- ん is a sound change of る, which is a contracted form of いる. See [this chart](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18159/5010). This る can be turned into ん in very casual Japanese. In particular, this る almost always turns into ん before ねん.
- ねん is a contraction of nothing. ねん is ねん, a sentence-end particle which is almost specific to Osaka dialect. It's like よ, のだ, のか, のです or のですか depending on the sentence. See: [ねん in the Kansai dialect](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19799/5010) and [Usage of ~まんねん (関西弁)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9966/5010)